# Show that all hyper planes of $M_n(K)$ contain at least one invertible matrix for $n\geq 2.$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $H$ be a hyperplane, then there exists a linear form $\phi$ such that $\ker\phi = H.$ Now since $\phi$ is a linear form in $M_n(K)$ there exists a matrix $A$ such that $$\phi(M) = \text{Tr}(AM).$$ Then we have that 
$$\ker \phi = H =  \{M\in M_{n}(K):\text{Tr}(AM) = 0\}.$$
We now have two cases:

1. If $\text{Tr}(A) = 0$ then we can take $M=I.$
2. If $\text{Tr}(A)\neq 0,$ then we want to take $M = I+ xE_{ij}$ for some suitable $x , i$ and $j.$ I was thinking that $$\text{Tr}(A(I+xE_{ij})) =\text{Tr}(A)+x\text{Tr}(AE_{ij})=\text{Tr}(A)+xa_{ji}.$$
   We could choose an element on the diagonal $i=j$ since the trace is not zero and then let $x=  - \text{Tr}(A)/a_{ii}.$ Then we would have an invertible matrix. Although I am not sure whether this approach would work. Perhaps someone has an idea?

Answer (score 1):

The existence of an invertible $M$ is guaranteed by a dimension argument. It is known (cf. thm 2 of Roy Meshulam, *On the maximal rank in a subspace of matrices*, Quart. J. Math. Oxford, 2(36): 225-229, 1985) that the maximum possible dimension of a subspace of singular $n\times n$ matrices is $n(n-1)$, which is strictly smaller than $\dim\{M\in M_n(K):\ \operatorname{tr}(AM)=0\}=n^2-1$ (or $n^2$ if $A=0$). Therefore, there is always some invertible $M$ that makes $AM$ traceless.

For a constructive proof, note that there always exist two invertible matrices $P$ and $Q$ such that $A=PDQ$ for some diagonal matrix $D$. So, we may pick $M=Q^{-1}CP^{-1}$, where $C$ is any invertible matrix with a zero diagonal, such as the circulant matrix $\pmatrix{\mathbf0&I_{n-1}\\ 1&\mathbf0^T}$.